# Looking for email notifications on trello

Tags: trello, notifications, date

I would like to know if there is a way to set email Notifications,

Specifically in checklist I set a date and would like an email when it hits that date.

Ex, I have X arriving on (date) and would like an email reminder on that date.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of steps you need to complete to fulfill this:

1. Start watching the card/list/item. Click the Watch button.
2. Set a due date reminder on the card. On the date, set the due date reminder.
3. Set the notification email frequency to "Instantly" by clicking the bell icon and "Change notification email frequency".
4. Done

You can read more [here](https://support.atlassian.com/trello/docs/receiving-trello-notifications/).